# Vercel Environment variable as hexadecimal

Tags: environment-variables, vercel

I need to use the environment variable as hexadecimal. (Ex. 0x240b3c1cc148d0ba)

It is working fine in my local with the use of .env file.

But it's not working in the Vercel Environment variable. It can be added but it doesn't work and crashed the page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue. My problem was that environment variables are all stored as strings, so you will have to cast to a number first.

I noticed this after installing the vercel CLI and then running `vercel env pull .env.local`.